# Сохранение авторизации на крупных ресурсах

Tags: php, javascript, шифрование

Как на крупных сайтах сохраняется авторизация даже после отключения вкладки или даже браузера? В любое время, когда ты не зайдешь, у тебя будет авторизована твоя страница. Куки или `localStorage` так же просто не запишешь, ибо эту информацию можно легко посмотреть в браузере. Поэтому я сразу JS убрал, потому что он выставляет всю информацию на виду. Сессии закрываются при определенных условиях довольно просто. Или все таки они используют `cookie`? Может кто-то знает про устройство таких систем.

Comment: Вам же уже написали в комментариях к предыдущему вопросу, что нужно использовать куки. Куки это естественно для аутентификации.

Comment: @Visman, а что с безопастностью такого метода. Только использовать шифрование?

Comment: Зачем шифрование для кук? Или вы хотите пароль в открытом виде в них хранить? Для безопасности ван нужно использовать https и установленные 5 и 6 параметры в setcookie() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php Читайте документацию, она для этого и написана.

Comment: В куки записывается токен и он проверяется при заходе на сайт. Вы легко это можете проверить для большого сайта просто удалив куки - у вас попросит пройти аутентификацию.

Answer (score 4):

используются `Cookie`.

В моем представлении нормальный алгоритм работает так:

Пользователь авторизуется (*например под логином root*), система генерирует уникальный ID и создает куку у пользователя, и например в базу заносит что с таким ID у нас юзер root, а так-же заносит служебную информацию (IP, user-agent).

При заходе снова на сайт: система смотрит есть ли у пользователя кука, если есть ищем соответствующую в БД и если такую находим чекаем соответствие IP и user-agent. Если все успешно - то норм. Если не совпадает IP (либо user-agent) то удаляем из БД такую запись.

Стоит так-же отметить что для крупных проектов характерна регенерация ключа: например уникальный ключ у нас: 12345 (в БД также соответственно записали). Так вот, регенерация это замена ключа (12345 на 67890) автоматически раз в какой-то срок (например раз в день). Система меняет значение ключа у пользователя и у себя в системе. Такой подход увеличивает стойкость защиты от хацкеров.

P.S. Стоит отметить что обычно хватает первых 50-70 символов user-agent для таких проверок.

P.S.2. Стоит отметить что генерируемые ключи должны быть уникальные для каждого промежутка времени (т.е. зависеть от него). Следовательно так-же нужно шифровать ключи уникально, чтобы хацкеры не смогли его расшифровать (не использовать в лоб обычные алгоритмы шифрования, использовать соли либо несколько алгоритмов сразу).