# Область хранения сессии и куки

Tags: php, сессия

Когда создаётся куки **setcookie("Cookie", "123");** Значение "123" хранится в браузере пользователя и занимает несколько байтов памяти компьютера.
Если же создаётся сессия session_start(); **$_SESSION['session'] = "456";** То значение "456" хранится на сервере и занимает память сервера верно?

У каждого браузера свой уникальный идентификатор сессии. Т.е. если заходить с одного браузера на сайт то у него будут одни и те же данные. Вопрос: как сделать чтобы в зависимости от того какой пользователь авторизовался для него был свой уникальный идентификатор сессии с его данными данными.

Comment: Обычно в сессию запихивают id пользователя, а остальные данные привязывают к этому id и хранят каким-нибудь другим способом

Comment: Прочитайте мой ответ в этом вопросе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/703962/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85/704066#704066

Comment: @andreymal Вот так? $_SESSION['users'][0] = 'Один пользователь'; $_SESSION['users'][2] = 'Другой пользователь';

Comment: Чтобы найти идентификатор существующей сессии используется session_start();, но как эта функция определит какая именно сессия пользователя используется?