# Каким образом сохранять куки в PHP?

Tags: php

Написал код для входа/регистрации пользователей, теперь ломаю голову, каким образом сохранять куки пользователям. Вся головоломка заключается в том, что пароли сохраняются в БД с помощью функции `password_hash()`, а хэш от неё сравнивается только с незахэшированным оригиналом. Авторизоваться то не проблема, т.к. оригинал пароля скрипту будет известен. А вот сохранить печеньки, не знаю как...

Comment: В чём проблема сохранять куки пользователя? Если выкинуть фразу "вся головоломка ... будет известен" (вы же не хотите в куку сохранять пароль в открытом виде), то непонятно, что мешает сохранять куки.

Comment: Да нет, сути не поняли. Нужно реализовать автовход с куками, вот я спрашиваю, как это сделать с паролем, захэшированным через `password_hash()`. Как создать куки, я знаю, а вот как реализовать не ясно

Comment: @AK Изначально хотел сохранять в куках хэшированный пароль и логин, а проблема в том, что хэши не сравнить.

Comment: В куках не хранят пароль и логин (легко украсть с клиента), в куках хранят идентификатор сессии на сервере и пароль проверяют не на клиенте, а на сервере. Вы по-прежнему хотите сохранить пароль в открытом виде на клиент и там его проверять? Или вы хотите понять, как устроены современные системы авторизации? В них нет нужды знать ни пароль в куки ни клиенте, нет и потребности на сервере хранить пароль в открытом виде.

Comment: Если вы потратите немного времени на поиск, то хотя бы с таким запросом "Безопасная авторизация через куки" вы найдёте множество решений и подробное описание всех подводных камней. Например [вот](https://habrahabr.ru/post/13726/).

Comment: setcookie();

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно все понял, то у Вас немножко неправильная логика авторизации.
Когда-то я хорошо расписал саму логику авторизации:

[Сохранение авторизации на крупных ресурсах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/703962/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85/704066#704066)

Comment: Могли бы просто предложить закрыть как дубликат. Этот же ответ по сути - комментарий или "ответ-ссылка", не более.