# Как изменять данные авторизованного пользователя в сессиях без релогина?

Tags: php, сессия

Вопрос в заголовке. Имеется авторизация по логину и паролю и проверка на админа:

```
if ($_SESSION['login'] -> admin === '1'){
 здесь уже меню админа, либо что-то еще.
}
```

При смене привилегии с админа на юзера, например, нужен релогин. Как избежать этого?

Comment: Зачем? Неужели так трудно выйти и зайти заново? Если хотите то сделайте так - создайте уник. ключ для пользователя и сделайте редирект на скрипт, передав туда ключ. По этому ключу можно будет понять какой пользователь и обратно его залогиниться, удалив после этот ключ.

Answer (score 0):

В сессии должен хранится только уникальный ключ. Каждое обращение к сайту = проверяем БД на наличие этого ключа, если есть (т.е. находится в системе), то по базе смотрим его привелегии.

P.S. [тут я описывал когда-то систему авторизации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/703962/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85/704066#704066), может поможет.